# Error in AndroidManifest.xml file in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

AndroidManifest.xml showing me 10 errors in the code below. I am unable to understand why it is showing these errors and how can I resolve this. Help me out from these errors.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.buis_talk">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <application
   android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="buis_talk"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image: These are the errors showing me in the android studio]

Comment: There is an extra `z` on cursor position

Comment: If you could also just hover over the red dashes of errors near the scroll bar - the IDE will give you more information on the error. You may also consider posting them here which could be helpful for others to better identify the issue.